# undefined in file path when trying to upload a file in React Application using ReactS3Uploader and SignedUrl

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am a newbie into React. I have been trying to upload file (images, json files etc) to AWS S3 bucket from a reactJS application using  ReactS3Uploader (version 4.8.0). I am following this example : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3-uploader

I have added the below code into one of my component where I want the file upload functionality :

```
<ReactS3Uploader
            getSignedUrl={getSignedUrl}
            accept="image/*"
            s3path="/uploads/test/"
            preprocess={this.onUploadStart}
            onSignedUrl={this.onSignedUrl}
            onProgress={this.onUploadProgress}
            onError={this.onUploadError}
            onFinish={this.onUploadFinish}
            signingUrlHeaders={{ }}
            signingUrlQueryParams={{ }}
            signingUrlWithCredentials={ true }      // in case when need to pass authentication credentials via CORS
            uploadRequestHeaders={{ 'x-amz-acl': 'public-read' }}  // this is the default
            contentDisposition="auto"
            scrubFilename={(filename) => filename.replace(/[^\w\d_\-.]+/ig, '')}
            inputRef={cmp => this.uploadInput = cmp}
            autoUpload={true}
            server="http://cross-origin-server.com"
        />
```

I have also created another component for getSignedUrl (S3SignedUrl.js) as follows (as described here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-s3-uploader ) :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import axios from '../../shared/axios';

function getSignedUrl(file, callback) {
  console.log('.........Inside getSignedUrl()>>file.nameeeee.........'+file.name)
  console.log('.........Inside getSignedUrl()>>file.size.........'+file.size)

  const filename = file.name;
  const params = {
    filename: file.name
    //contentType: file.type
  };

  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
  }

  axios.post(`/api/link/admin/v1/s3/sign?filename=${filename}`, {headers: headers})
  .then(data => {
     console.log('data.data.signedUrl>>>>>>>>>>>'+data.data.signedUrl)
     callback(data);
     return data.data
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
export default getSignedUrl;
```

I have a groovy based backend api (springboot application) which creates the s3 signed url in the following format :

```
{
    "signedUrl": “<complete signed url>”,
    "uploadPath": “mybucket/apidocs/dev/version/logo/04137a9c-fb60-48dd-ae0f-c53d78e4e379/logo.png",
    "expiresAt": 1552083549794
}
```

I am successfully able to call my groovy /s3/sign url from my react application through (S3SignedUrl.js which uses Axios) but right after that when ReactS3Uploader component tries to upload the file to the AWS S3 bucket, it gives me an error with HTTP 403.
When I see into the network tab (by inspecting within the google chrome), the underlying call being made my ReactS3Uploader component is 
PUT https://localhost:3000/apps/gateway/undefined with Http 403

I am not sure what is undefined here within the url.  Shouldn’t ReactS3Uploader component automatically  be doing a HTTP PUT to the signedURL ?
I do see some fixes in react-s3-uploader version 4.6.2 around undefined in file path when not providing s3path property. https://changelogs.md/github/odysseyscience/react-s3-uploader/
But not sure if it has anything too do with the problem I am getting. By the way I am using using  version 4.8.0.

Just to confirm  I can successfully upload the file using that SignedURL manually thru curl.

Any help here would highly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I've been searching for something similar and came across this.
You should have `callback(data.data);`.
ReactS3Uploader will redirect to an undefined URL if it's configured to use a getSignedUrl function and is not returned a signedUrl field.